# Entity Framework Code Only Relationship Not Being Read

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, code-first

*(This looks like a long question, but it's not really, honest!)*

I am trying to get a simple proof of concept working with Entity Framework 4 and the CTP 3 version of Code Only. It feels like I'm missing something really obvious and simple.

I have this following test which is failing:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ParentChildTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ChildRead_DatabaseContainsRelatedObjects_ParentIsNotNull()
    {
        var ctx = GetMyObjectContext();
        var child = ctx.Children.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Single();
        var parent = child.ParentTable;
        Assert.That(parent, Is.Not.Null);
    }

    // GetMyObjectContext etc...
}
```

The read of `child` works fine and I get back a `ChildTable` whose `ParentTableId` value is '1' as I would expect, but the `ParentTable` property is NULL. I do not expect this because my POCOs have all virtual properties (see below) and EF4 has lazy loading enabled by default.

What am I missing?

---

***Database***

```
create table parent_table
(
    parent_table_id   int identity(1,1) primary key,
    parent_table_name varchar(50) not null,
    display_name      varchar(50)
)

create table child_table
(
    child_table_id   int identity(1,1) primary key,
    child_table_name varchar(50) not null,
    parent_table_id  int not null
)

alter table child_table add constraint FK_child_table__parent_table
foreign key (parent_table_id) references parent_table(parent_table_id)
```

***POCO Entities***

```
public class ParentTable
{
    public virtual int    Id          { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name        { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class ChildTable
{
    public virtual int         Id            { get; set; }
    public virtual string      Name          { get; set; }
    public virtual int         ParentTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentTable ParentTable   { get; set; }
}
```

***Entity Configurations***

```
public class ParentTableConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<ParentTable>
{
    public ParentTableConfiguration()
    {
        MapSingleType(pt => new
        {
            parent_table_id   = pt.Id,
            parent_table_name = pt.Name,
            display_name      = pt.DisplayName,
        })
        .ToTable("dbo.parent_table");

        Property( pt => pt.Id   ).IsIdentity();
        Property( pt => pt.Name ).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class ChildTableConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<ChildTable>
{
    public ChildTableConfiguration()
    {
        MapSingleType(ct => new
        {
            child_table_id   = ct.Id,
            child_table_name = ct.Name,
            parent_table_id  = ct.ParentTableId,
        })
        .ToTable("dbo.child_table");

        Property( ct => ct.Id   ).IsIdentity();
        Property( ct => ct.Name ).IsRequired();

        Relationship(ct => ct.ParentTable)
            .HasConstraint((ct, pt) => ct.ParentTableId == pt.Id);
    }
}
```

*(Thanks for reading this far!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as understand you just do not load this navigation property.

This will result in eager loading.

`var child = ctx.Children.Include("ParentTable").Where(c => c.Id == 1).Single();`

Or you could enable lazy loading by setting `ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`